# Laravel Continuous Integration with Gitlab-runner in offline environment (CentOS 7)

Tags: apache, continuous-integration, centos7, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm developing a website on a totally offline environment. also, I use gitlab runner for CI and the host is CentOS 7.

the problem is that gitlab runner uses `gitlab-runner` user on centos for deploying laravel application and apache uses `apache` user for running laravel.
I got `Permission denied` error on apache til I changed ownership of files. after that I get this error on apache log:

`Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: The stream or file "storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied`

it seems that some vendor libraries like `monolog` want to write error or debug logs onto `storage/logs/laravel.log` but it gets permission denied. :(

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

buildBash:
  stage: build
  script:
    - bash build.sh

testBash:
  stage: test
  script:
    - bash test.sh

deployBash:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - sudo bash deploy.sh
```

**build.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

set -xe

# creating env file from production file
cp .env.production .env

# initializing laravel
php artisan key:generate
php artisan config:cache

# database migration
php artisan migrate --force
```

**deploy.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

PWD=$(pwd)'/public'
STG=$(pwd)'/storage'

ln -s $PWD /var/www/html/public
chown apache.apache -R /var/www/html/public
chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/public
chmod -R 775 $STG
```

Am I using gitlab runner correct? how can I fix the permission denied error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SELinux**

I found the problem and it was selinux, like always it was selinux and I ignored it at the begining

---

**What's the problem**:

you can see selinux context on files with `ls -lZ` command, by default all files on www are `httpd_sys_content_t`, the problem is that selinux just allow apache to read these files. you should change `storage` and `bootstrap/cache` context so it can be writable.

there are 4 apache context type:

- *httpd_sys_content_t*: read-only directories and files
- *httpd_sys_rw_content_t*: readable and writable directories and files used by Apache
- *httpd_log_t*: used by Apache for log files and directories
- *httpd_cache_t*: used by Apache for cache files and directories

**What to do:**

first of all install `policycoreutils-python` for better commands

`yum install -y policycoreutils-python`

after installing `policycoreutils-python` the `semanage` command is available, so you can change file context like this:

`semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/var/www/html/laravel/storage(/.*)?"
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/var/www/html/laravel/bootstrap/cache(/.*)?"`

don't forget to commit the changes by this command:

`restorecon -Rv /var/www/html/laravel/storage
restorecon -Rv /var/www/html/laravel/bootstrap/cache`

the problem is solved :)

ref: http://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/web-servers-linux/configuring-selinux-policies-for-apache-web-servers/